# how to launch an android app with custom url scheme

Tags: android, android-activity, url-scheme, deep-linking

I want to launch my app from a custom URL scheme. I checked the deep links section on dev android and here is a snippet of my code. This doesnt seem to fire though with a URL that looks like : myApp://?host=myhost.com

Manifest :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="myApp" />
</intent-filter>
```

In the activity which is my main activity, i have :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = intent.getData();
if (uri != null) {
    String host = uri.getQueryParameter("host");
}
```

The app does not launch when i have email that has the url as a hyperlink.
Also, what would be a good way to test this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, edit your `IntentFilter`

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

**EDIT**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>


<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: My action is MAIN which is the entry pt. into the app. Wouldnt it work with MAIN  ?

Comment: Okay I've edited my question. This is how you can have two separate `IntentFilters`.

Comment: Cool thanks but i found that you can combine them into a single intent filter and order them.

Comment: I am able to successfully launch apps with URL style calls, however, its launching the app from within my own app, not in a new window.  What intent can I use to force the app to a new window?

Answer (score 1):

The browser converts the scheme to lowercase, so you need to change the data tag to

```
<data android:scheme="myapp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

k it looks like ACTION_VIEW is a must to support custom URI schemes. I can add VIEW and MAIN though which gets it to work.